# Remove nulls from an array in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

Want to remove nulls from an array in hive/sql

for example : array is ['1',null] after converting to string values it should be '1' only.

to split the array I am using below:

```
concat_ws( ",", array_val)

this gives : 1,null

required output : 1
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regexp_replace to remove null from concatenated string:

```
hive> select regexp_replace('null,1,2,null,2,3,null','(,+null)|(^null,)','');
OK
1,2,2,3
Time taken: 6.006 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```